# Get the max value of un-hidden cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that has 20 rows and the table un-hides the amount of rows specified in the cell above my table. so if I put in 5 into the cell, 5 of the 20 rows will be un-hidden.
So now I would like to get the MAX of the say 5 cells that are now unhidden. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUBTOTAL(104,RANGE)
```

104 will give you the max of the unhidden cells. If you replace 104 with 4 it will operate as the normal MAX function UNLESS you are filtering the rows using the built in Excel table function.

Comment: SUBTOTAL **always** ignores rows not visible due to filtering (using 4 or 104), so it's not really a "normal MAX function".

Comment: Excel Help Documentation on SUBTOTAL states "number 1 to 11 (includes hidden values) or 101 to 111 (ignores hidden values) that specifies which function to use in calculating subtotals within a list." and I just tested it and 4 appears to be working as the normal MAX function in a regular filtered table and manually hidden rows. Houdini you actually made me test this in Excel in utter shock.

Comment: "hidden values" in this context means those rows hidden with Hide command, so 104 ignores rows hidden with Hide, 4 doesn't......but both of them ignore rows hidden by filtering as stated also in Help - i.e. "The SUBTOTAL function ignores any rows that are not included in the result of a filter, no matter which function_num value you use"

Comment: Upvote my question seeing that you guys had a little discussion about the subject

Comment: Houdini how do you hide something without it being the result of a filter?... Mike Barnes - Up voted.

Comment: Upvoted.....I tested again, I seem to be having trouble getting SUBTOTAL(4,range) to behave differently to SUBTOTAL(104,range) - both are ignoring rows hidden with hide (??) but certainly I don't get the same results with =MAX(range) and =SUBTOTAL(4,range) - the latter will ignore filtered out values

Comment: I think my eyes might be playing tricks on me. My hide function started to lock up and it wouldn't let me unhide a row. Might have just been a glitch. How do you hide a row without it being the result of a filter now it is not working even if I right click and hide a row.

Comment: the hiding and filtering don't seem to play nice together in the same table, but if I have a table with values 1 to 10 then manually hide the 10 value MAX and 4 both show 10 still as expected but 104 shows 9 as expected. If I then filter by another column SUBTOTAL with 4 and 104 both give me the same results, not 10, MAX always returns 10

Comment: @barryhoudini I tested with 1000 to 1(increments of 100). With nothing hidden all return 1000. When I right click the row header and select hide; the results become `Max()` AND `Subtotal(4,range)` = 1000 while `Subtotal(104,range)` returns 900. If I then Unhide that row and use the Filter to filter out 1000, `MAX()` remains at 1000, While Both `Subtotal(4,range)` AND `Subtotal(104,range)` return 900. So, `MAX()` returns max hidden/filtered/or not `Subtotal(4,range)` ignores filtered values but not hidden value, And `Subtotal(104,range)` returns MAX *visible* value. Exactly as you state.

Comment: I added to my answer since Excel doesn't consider table filters actually hiding a row. Which might I add is VERY GLITCHY!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

```
=SUBTOTAL(104,your_range)
```